# Make ng-show work for 0 length strings ""

Tags: angularjs-ng-show

Is there a way to make ng-show work for 0 length strings ''?

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('app', appController);
function appController($scope) {
  $scope.zero = '';
  $scope.string = 'string';
  $scope.n = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app">
  <div ng-show="zero">MAKE THIS APPEAR</div>
  <div ng-show="string">This appears, as usual</div>
  <div ng-show="n">This should not appear, as usual</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ng-show="zero.length >= 0"
```

If you want it only for zero length strings you can change it to:

```
ng-show="zero.length === 0"
```

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/K7DyPukQHcDyLAUw4Dua